# Git P4 - No files to submit

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I have cloned a P4 repo with git-p4, did all my changes and committed to master.

Then I do a `git p4 rebase` with the following output

```
Performing incremental import into refs/remotes/p4/master git branch
Depot paths: //MYP4PATH
No changes to import!
Rebasing the current branch onto remotes/p4/master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

Then I do a `git p4 submit`, the process marks all files for editing (the files are the ones I modified, those are correct), asks me for a commit message, after I create one I get

```
Change 46537 created.
Submitting change 46537.
No files to submit.
Command failed: ['p4', '-r', '3', 'submit', '-i']
Submission cancelled, undoing p4 changes.
```

This has happened with every change I tried to submit, no matter how small.

How can I fix this so I can submit changes with git?

Comment: There are multiple versions of git-p4 around, you might want to try different ones to see if any work.

Comment: Possibly there's a way to get more verbose output, to try and work out what's happening.